# How to read the decimal precision value from spark dataframe using python

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe. From which I have to read the column names , datatype and precision values if any.

I am able to read the name and type as below

```
    for f in df.schema.fields:
       name = f.name
       type = f.dataType.typeName()
```

The dataframe schema looks like this-

```
   [StructField(orgid,StringType,true), StructField(customerid,DecimalType(15,5),true), StructField(oppid,IntegerType,true)]
```

In the above schema I have to read the decimal precision value i.e., `(15,5)`. Is there any way ? 
Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether the data type is Decimal with `isinstance`, and then the precision value can be extracted from `.precision` and `.scale`:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DecimalType

for f in df.schema.fields:
    if isinstance(f.dataType, DecimalType):
        print(f.dataType.precision, f.dataType.scale)

# 15 5
```